# Спрайты для UI плохого качества

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Столкнулся с проблемой, что UI спрайты плохого качества (с зазубриными пиксельно). Пробовал в интернете разные варианты решений, но как был спрайт пиксельный, так и остался

Сначала пробовал увеличить качество изображения (с 512 до 1024).  - не помогла

Далее я следовал в интернете инструкциям по изменению спрайта, про которые все писали (не помогло):

"Filter mode -> Point (no filter)"

"Max size -> 8192" или в их же качество

"Compression -> High quality или None"


Пожалуйста, подскажите что сделать

Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Billinear / RGBA`. `Point` для пиксельарта.

Comment: судя по скрину, все ваши проблемы от того, что ради маленького изображение в самой игре вы используете просто гигантский спрайт 1024х1024. Соответственно, юнити, чтобы отрисовать его столь маленьким приходится использовать фильтры минификации (вы используете на экране сильно меньше пикселей, чем есть в спрайте) - отсюда и артефакты на полученном изображении. Попробуйте использовать сам спрайт, например, 128х128

Comment: Изначально само изображение было 512x512.
Спасибо, помогло. Я бы ещё добавил немного размытость по краям спрайта сделать (т.е. в самом изображении)

Можете добавить свой ответ, чтобы я засчитал его верным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы используете слишком большой спрайт для отрисовки маленького участка на экране. Для того, чтобы отрисовать спрайт в меньшем размере, чем он есть сам по себе ( а у вас это 1024х1024 ), юнити приходится уменьшать изображение до размеров, примерно 128*128 (на глаз судя по вашему скрину).

Для этого применяются фильтры минификации (алгоритмы, которые решают какие пиксели исходного спрайта "выкинуть", чтобы получить изображение меньшего размера), результат работы которых и сказывается на потере качества изображения при его отрисовке на экран.

По этому, если вы используете спрайт меньше размером, например 128х128, то качество отрисованной картинки должно быть лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Filter mode -> Bilinear

Так же я думаю ты мог напортачить с объектом картинки на сцене. Это должен быть Image, у которого scale = 1

- в настройках канваса pixel perfect убери

Comment: Filter mode -> Bilinear - поставил
Scale изначально стоял на 1x1x1. Ничего не изменено
Pixel perfect изначально не стоял.

Comment: Как было, так и осталось

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому нибуть поможет:

Вот из-за чего пикселизировать изображение у меня, я поставил восьмую часть от графики а нужно "Full Res".

[image]